# Change portfolio url in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, portfolio

I have two pages showing portfolio posts, one of them shows the posts with parent category 'products', and the other one the posts with parent category 'projects'.

The problem is that the portfolio post page url is: 'www.xxx.com/portfolio/product-name' inside products and 'www.xxx.com/portfolio/project-name' inside projects, and what I want is: 'www.xxx.com/PRODUCTS/product-name' and 'www.xxx.com/PROJECTS/project-name'.

I found the function 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio' ), but it changes both of them, and I need a diferent name for each one.

```
register_post_type( 
    'port', 
    array( 
      'label' => 'Portfolio', 
      'public' => true, 
      'show_ui' => true, 
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true, 
      'rewrite' => 
          array( 
             'slug' => 'portfolio', 
             'with_front' => false 
          ), 
      'hierarchical' => true, 
      'menu_position' => 5, 
      'supports' => 
          array( 'title', 
                 'page-attributes', 
                 'editor', 
                 'excerpt', 
                 'thumbnail'
           ) 
   ) 
);
```

Anyone knows how to do that??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you show us how do you change `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio' ),`?

Comment: With the register custom post function:

register_post_type( 'port', array(
  'label' => 'Portfolio',
  'public' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
  'rewrite'            => array(
   'slug'       => 'portfolio',
   'with_front' => false
  ),
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'menu_position' => 5,
  'supports' => array(
  'title',
        'page-attributes',
  'editor',
  'excerpt',
  'thumbnail')
  ) 
 );

You can change 'portfolio' to whatever you want.